# C: How to put a String in every Spaces of a 2d char Array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, sudoku

I'm programming a sudoku-solver in C. The structer is that I have 2d char Arrays.

The first one is the actuall Sudoku all the empty(0) & full spots are saved into from a txt. file and it is also the my output in the end.

The second one is also 2d char Array with all the possible Values for the empty spaces in the first Array(0 in the first Array) . In the beginning I have to initalize the second 2d char Array with all the possible values "123456789" and cross out one after another until only one possible value is left and that one is saved in the first Array.

No my question. How can I put a String like "123456789" in a 2d char Array.

I tried the following things:

```
int j, k;
char possible_values[9][9];

for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    for(k=0;k<9;k++){
        possible_values[j][k] = "123456789";
    }
}     


for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    for(k=0;k<9;k++){
        printf("%c", possible_values[j][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

and

```
int j, k;
char *possible_values[9][9];
char string [] = "123456789";

for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    for(k=0;k<9;k++){
        possible_values[j][k] = &string;
    }
}     


for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    for(k=0;k<9;k++){
        printf("%c", *possible_values[j][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

but all it ever prints aut is a 9x9 grid with '9', in every spaces, because it only puts one char in the array, but how can I put the whole String in the Array ?

**EDIT**
I have the solution, thanks for all the help !!

Comment: Instead of putting a `string` at each element in the array, put a single `char` at each space and set the value of that char to `1-9` as needed. A `char` has `8-bits` and can handle `0-255`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store address of string in each element of 2d-array use:

```cpp
for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    for(k=0;k<9;k++){
        possible_values[j][k] = string; // & not needed
    }
}
```

**Note:** all pointers in `possible_values` point the same memory (they are not a copies of string), so if `possible_values[1][2]` is changed, all other `possible_values[j][k]` also changed).

To output strings (all strings will be the same - see NOTE above) use the loop:

```cpp
char *possible_values[9][9];

for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    for(k=0;k<9;k++){
         printf("%s", possible_values[j][k]);
    }
```

`%s` means string, `%c` means single character.

**EDIT:**

I suppose you need something like that:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    int j, k;
    char possible_values[9][9][10]; // 10th element in 3rd dimension is for '\0' 
    char string [] = "123456789";

    for(j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<9;k++)
        {
            memcpy(possible_values[j][k], string, 10);
        }
    } 

    for(j=0;j<9;j++){
        for(k=0;k<9;k++){
            printf("%s ", possible_values[j][k]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now any `possible_values[j][k]` is independent data and you can exclude elements from possible values of each cell.

Comment: Thanks, that is perfekt !! You saved my day :]

Answer (score 1):

Use one character for the assignment instead of a string of them.

```
char initters[] = "123456789";

for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    for(k=0;k<9;k++){
        possible_values[j][k] = innitters[k];
    }
}
```

It is an two dimensional array of chars.
It makes some sort of sense that each element of the array is a char.

Comment: Each element contains the possible values for that cell, not a guessed (or correct) single value. It is a set of values, represented by a string. As the game is solved, that string is reduced to a single character.

Comment: I might consider a 3 dimentional array, with the third element being a bit map showing what digits remain.

Comment: Or a 2D array of `short` and just use the first 10 bits. (but, I guess memory is cheap these days...)

Answer (score 1):

`possible_values` is a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) of numerical values, which are represented as a character string. So this:

```
char *possible_values[9][9];
char initial_values [] = "123456789";
```

is good.

You just need to use the correct syntax for accessing and printing strings.

```
for(j=0;j<9;j++){
  for(k=0;k<9;k++){
    //no need for &, as initial_values and possible_values are both strings
    possible_values[j][k] = initial_values; 
  }
}     

for(j=0;j<9;j++){
   for(k=0;k<9;k++){
     //printf with %s to print a string, no need for *
     printf("The possible values of cell [%d][%d] are [%s]\n",
         j, k,
         possible_values[j][k]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```